# Fourier Analysis of Prime Counting Function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fourier-analysis, prime-numbers, fourier-series

I was thinking about the following:

Denote $\pi(x)$ as the prime counting function such that:
$$
\pi(x) = \#\text{ of prime numbers}\leq x
$$
It is well known from the prime number theorem that
$$
\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}
$$
and
$$
\pi(x) \sim \text{Li}(x),\quad \text{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\frac{1}{\ln t}\,dt.
$$
Note the following:
if $A(x) \sim B(x)\implies A(x)/B(x) = 1 \text{ as }x\to\infty$ and $A(x), B(x)\to\infty \text{ as }x\to\infty$.

If $C(x)$ is a function such that $n \leq C(x) \leq k$ then:

$$(A(x) + n)/B(x) \leq (A(x) + C(x))/B(x) \leq (A(x) + k)/B(x)$$

$$A(x)/B(x) + n/B(x) \leq A(x)/B(x) + C(x)/B(x) \leq A(x)/B(x) + k/B(x)$$

If x is taken to infinity:

$$1 + 0 \leq A(x)/B(x) + C(x)/B(x) \leq 1 + 0$$

$$\rightarrow A(x) + C(x) ~ B(x)$$

What interests me is that since we already know that:

$$\pi(x) \sim x/\ln(x)$$

and from above that $x/ln(x) +$ any number of functions of the form $A(b(x)) ~ \pi(x)$

Can we not try to do some sort of fourier analysis on the function:

$$\pi(x) - x/\ln(x) $$

or

$\pi(x) - \text{Li}(x)$?

Comment: I fail to understand what your saying at the point in which you introduce the function $c(x)$, I recommend formatting your text properly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " do some fourier analysis on the function $\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ ". If you are asking for a good estimate on the difference between $\pi(x)$ and $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, then this would be asymptotic to $\text{Li}(x)-\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, this is because the logarithmic integral is a much better approximation to $\pi(x)$ then $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, so with that said it would probably be more interesting to study the behavior of $\pi(x)-\text{Li(x)}$.

Comment: basically, I want to see if there are any patterns or noticeable trends in the difference, that can be approximated by sines

Comment: The difference between $\pi(x)$ and $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ can already be approximated very well, I think the question to ask would be regarding the difference of $\pi(x)$ and $\text{Li}(x)$.

Comment: The [explicit formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formula) for the prime counting function is perhaps the 'correct' mixture of fourier analysis (using the zeros of the Riemann zeta function) and asymptotics (employing the logarithmic integral function). The PNT $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$ is equivalent to $\psi(x)\sim x$, where $\psi(x)$ is the chebyshev function, a variant way of measuring prime growth. A more direct fourier expansion of $\psi(x)-x$ also exists, a variant of the explicit formula. See the link for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The purpose of $\zeta(s)$ is to perform Fourier analysis on $\pi(e^u)$ :**

$$\zeta(s) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} \quad \implies \quad \ln \zeta(s) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$$

i.e. it is the $\color{red}{\text{Laplace transform}}$ of $\sum_{p^k} \frac{1}{k}\delta(u-\ln p^k)$ $\qquad \scriptstyle \text{(or if you prefer, }\hat{f}(\xi ) =\ln \zeta(\sigma+2i \pi \xi) \text{ is the Fourier transform of } f(u) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{1}{\scriptstyle k \ p^{ \sigma k}}\delta(u-\ln p^k)$)

[Integrating by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), you get
$$\ln \zeta(s) = s \int_0^\infty J(e^u) e^{-su}du$$
where $J(x) = \sum_{p^k < x}\frac{1}{k} = \pi(x) + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$.

i.e. 
$$\boxed{\frac{\ln \zeta(s) }{s} = h(s) + \int_0^\infty \pi(e^u) e^{-su}du}$$
where $h(s) = \int_0^\infty (J(e^u)-\pi(e^u))e^{-su}du$ is analytic and bounded for $Re(s) > 1/2+\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm sorry, please can you tell me if your integral expression for $\log \zeta(s)$ is the same integral identity $$\ln \zeta(s) = s \int_0^\infty J(x) x^{-s-1}dx,$$ from **Wikipedia's** article for the Riemann Zeta?

Comment: @user243301 yes of course $x = e^u$

Comment: Sorry, since were mistakes in my calculations with such change of variable. Now thanks your hint I see those factors in the integrand, but how do you solve the lower limit of integration $\int_0 du$ : I say when one has $x=0$, using such change of variable I need to solve the $0=e^u$. How do you know that your lower limit of integration is $0=u$?

Comment: @user243301 I meant $\int_{\ln 2}^\infty J(e^u) e^{-su} du$, since $J(x) = 0$ for $x < 2$

Comment: Sorry for my insistence, and thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform Fourier analysis on $\pi(x)$. Here are two plots of a Fourier series for $\pi'(x)$, i.e. the derivative of $\pi(x)$, with a frequency evaluation limit $f=1$ for the first plot and $f=4$ for the second plot. The two plots below illustrate the general relationship that this Fourier series always evaluates to $2f$ times the step size of $\pi(x)$ at integer values of $x$.

[Fourier Series for π'(x) Evaluated at f=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5nYY.jpg)

[Fourier Series for π'(x) Evaluated at f=4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPvJL.jpg)

Comment: the Fourier series of $\pi'(x)$ ? I don't follow you. You meant the discrete Fourier transform of $x(p) = 1, x(n) = 0$ otherwise, $n \in 1 \ldots N$ ?