# zeros of the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I watched a video explaining that using the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, we can approximate the prime counting function to have a pretty high accuracy

I would like to know, how many zeros we must have (find) to obtain all primes less than 100 for example ? or this doesn't work like that ? if so what can we benefit from two or three zeros (let's say the first ones) ?

Also, why is this a "high accuracy", and not exact result ?

*video link time 15:45 : https://youtu.be/dktH8hJadyU?t=948*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_for_L-functions#Riemann's_explicit_formula

Comment: The guaranteed magnitude of the error term $|Li(x)-\pi(x)|$ is dramtically smaller if the Riemann hypothesis is true, but still there is no direct way to determine $\pi(10^{300})$ or the $10^{300}$ th prime.

Comment: There are recursive methods to determine $\pi(x)$ for which we arrived around $10^{26}$ (the exponent in the current record might be somewhat smaller or larger) , but they neither allow calculating exact values for huge $x$. In particular, we cannot determine huge primes this way.

Comment: thanks @Peter, so if we discover a new way that allows calculating exact values for huge x, a direct way to determine π(10^300) or the 10^300 th prime, we may say that the Riemann hypothesis is no longer interesting ?

Comment: No, the riemann hypothesis is a very important conjecture, it would be very useful to prove it. When I googled "riemann hypothesis" , the first (!) hit was a claim that it has been proven - quite sad. Why people over and over again claim such things, no idea.

Comment: To obtain $\pi(x)$ using the zeta zeros see the papers from this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008653) (around $70$ billions zeros were needed to compute $\pi(10^{24})\;$).